# Does the interval (a, a) contain any real numbers, assuming the interval is on the real line?

Tags: real-analysis

The title pretty much describes my question.  I apologize if the language is not as mathematically precise as it could be.  Many thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hardly. The interval $(a, a)$ is empty; it doesn't even contain $a$.

On the otherhand, $[a, a] = \{a\}$.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I thought.  Many thanks for the quick reply.